# IP addr: How many discrete address-port combos are there on an network connection, given IP's output?

Tags: ip

Suppose I am connected to the internet via `eth0`, and run the following:

```
ip addr | grep eth0 | grep inet
```

---

The command outputs the following string of information:

```
inet 123.213.50.19/20 brd 123.213.63.255 scope global eth0
```

Where I've anonymized the mask numbers, and kept the spacing between the subnet numbers consistent.

My question amounts to: given the `/20` address above, and the `brd ...` address, and the array of ports, what are all total combinations of ip address and port number that I can choose to host something on from that ethernet connection?

Is it:

```
2^12 * (portCount - portsReserved)?
```

And, when calculating them, do I simply take the array of values, starting at:

```
123.213.50.19
```

And ending at:

```
123.213.50.19 + 2^12
```

And choose any address in there?

Comment: For the number of hosts on the network, and min/max IP address, see any website such as http://jodies.de/ipcalc or similar. The 123.213.50.19/20 network contains the 4094 hosts between 123.213.48.1 and 123.213.63.254.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing#IPv4_CIDR_blocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
inet 123.213.50.19/20 brd 123.61.255
```

means that the interface is configured to use IPv4 address 123.213.50.19, on a subnet with a 20-bit mask, and the broadcast address is 123.61.255 (it should be 123.213.63.255).

The subnet mask determines which IP addresses your system can “talk” to without going through a gateway, it doesn’t determine how many IP addresses your system can *use*. You can assign more IP addresses to your interface if you want (and nothing else is using them), but that’s not automatic.

Ignoring network constraints, the number of possibilities is determined by the available subnet bits (32 - 20, 12) and the number of ports (65536), minus unusable values such as the broadcast address. The lowest possible IP address in the subnet is the masked address completed with all zeroes, plus one typically: 123.213.48.1 (48 is 00110000b). The highest possible address is the masked address completed with all ones, minus one: 123.213.63.254 (63 is 00111111b).

Comment: that is awesome, thank you. and, edited the broadcast val -- didn't know that was fixed.